# Cascade Multi Select Kendo Dropdown on change of another Multi Select Kendo Dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I have a situation where I have two multi select Kendo dropdowns and on select of first multi select dropdown I wants to populate another multi select dropdown.

**1st MultiSelect Kendo DD:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
   .Name("FirstDropDown").Placeholder("-- Select --")
   .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.BusinessData, "Id", "Name"))
   .Enable(true)
   .AutoBind(false).Events(e => e.Change("onFirstDropDownChange"))
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px" })
 )
```

**2nd MultiSelect Kendo DD:**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
   .Name("project")
   .Placeholder("-- Select --")
   .DataTextField("ProjectName")
   .DataValueField("Id")
   .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
   .DataSource(source =>
    {
       source.Read(read =>
       {
          read.Action("GetProjectByBu", "Reports").Data("filterProjects");
       })
    .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
   .Enable(true)
   .AutoBind(false).Events(e => e.Change("onProjectChange"))
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px" })
 )
```

**JS Code:**

```
function filterProjects() {
    return {
        buID: $("#FirstDropDown").data("kendoMultiSelect").input.val()
    };
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I was trying to make AJAX call in `onFirstDropDownChange` function but that was not working as *DataSource* is not binding with 2nd dropdown.

**Constraints:**

1. I doesn't want to load data on both dropdowns at first.
2. Values of 2nd dropdown is dependent upon 1st dropdown, means all values selected in 1st dorpdown will be sent to database through MVC Controller and fetch the data from there.

**What I wants to do:**

When I will select any value in 1st multi select dropdown my 2nd multi select dropdown will be populated as per values selected in 1st dropdown.

Comment: Have you already read the docs here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/multiselect/how-to/cascade/cascading-multiselects? Can you show JS function inside `onFirstDropDownChange` & `onSecondDropDownChange`?

Comment: I have edited my 2nd dropdown code, where I am trying to fetch out the data using AJAX, but the problem is this code will fire when page is loaded and at that time 1st dropdown doesn't have any value, so no data is pulled out. In onFirstDropDownChange I wants to trigger ajax call or wants to refresh the part of my web page where 2nd dropdown is there. And yes I have already gone through the Telerik link, in this example data is prepopulated in both dropdowns which I don't want.

Comment: With `autoBind` set to false, the drop down should wait until either the drop down is clicked, or a manual `read()` is triggered on the dataSource. You may have to disable the second multiselect until selection is made in the first, then in your `change` `onFirstDropDownChange` function, you can enable the second multiselect and trigger the [`read()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data). (`secondMultiselect.dataSource.read();`)

Comment: Additionally you need to declare second DDL `dataSource` by client-side function e.g. `var projectDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ type: "odata", serverFiltering: true, transport: { read: { url: "@Url.Action(...)", }, }});` Since autobinding is disabled, data sources for both DDL should be bound and read manually during `click` or `change` events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this problem by using AJAX call, below are the detailed steps:

1. First, I have attached one JavaScript function `onFirstDropDownChange` on `FirstDropDown`.
2. Then in `onFirstDropDownChange` js function, I get all selected values in first dropdown and make an synchronous AJAX call and bind data in 2nd drop down, below is code for same.

var multiselect = $("#FirstDropDown").data("kendoMultiSelect");

```
var i; var stringArray = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < multiselect.dataItems().length; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = parseInt(multiselect.dataItems()[i].Value,32);
    }

var postedData = { businessIds: stringArray };
var projectDataSource;

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

//AJAX Call
$.ajax({
    url: '/Reports/GetProjectByBu',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: postedData,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        projectDataSource = data;
    }
});

//Update DataSource of 2nd dropdown
$("#project").data("kendoMultiSelect").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: projectDataSource }));
```

Hope this will help you, if you are trying to looking for similar kind of solution.